# Query on SQL Query

Tags: sql

I have a query on a problem statement of SQL query.
The question is like this: "Fetch the name of each employee in uppercase and arrange the data in descending order."

My question is, can I use upper case of the column 'first_name' as well as order by desc at the same query.

I tried as:

```
select upper(first_name)
from employee
order by first_name desc;
```

But it is not working. Throwing an error: FAILED: SemanticExpression[Error: 10004]: Line table invalid alias or column reference 'first_name': (possible column names are: _c0)

I tried with select upper(first_name) from employee group by first_name;

It is working but with this it is not possible to order the data in descending order.

Someone please help on this problem statement:

> Fetch the name of each employee in uppercase and arrange the data in descending order."

Comment: I removed the inconsistent database tags.  Tag with the database you are really using.  This is undoubtedly database-specific, because your query is valid SQL.

Answer (score 0):

Although your query work, I would recommend repeating the `upper()` in the `order by`:

```
select upper(first_name)
from employee
order by upper(first_name) desc;
```

You might even want `select distinct`.

In any case, in a query that is not an aggregation query or `select distinct`, you can order by any column or expression, even those not in the `select` (although some databases might restrict this).  In an aggregation query, you an only `order by` columns and expressions that are valid after the aggregation -- the `group by` keys, aggregation functions, and expressions comprised of those.

Comment: Thanks. It worked. I gave an alias to the upper(first_name) and used that in order by statement. So it worked. select upper(First_Name) as Name from employee order by Name desc;